# Bathroom removal?

Tags: bathroom, basement, code-compliance

We are selling our home and just received our municipal inspection results.

They are asking us to remove our full bathroom in the basement because it "no longer" meets minimum height requirements (6'8" our is currently 6'6")

There is no way to raise the ceiling as it is already up to the joists for the main level.

I understand that codes change over time, but shouldn't this be grandfathered or something since the bathroom existed and passed inspection when I purchased the home?

I cannot find any information on anybody else being asked to remove a bathroom.

Comment: Was the original build permitted?  Usually, depending on jurisdiction, if it was permitted and inspected, then it would be grandfathered.  However, if it wasn't, then current code applies.

Comment: If the bath was permitted or part of the original build I would tell them codes change but unless they would like to make up the difference in sales price you have no plans to decommission a functional bathroom. I agree with Chris.

Comment: Might be easier to take a buyer out of the equation than take a bathroom out of the equation?

Comment: Who is "they" exactly? Is the buyer honestly asking you to remove a bathroom? If this is the case then walk away from that buyer. Imagine what would happen if you removed the bathroom at your expense just to have the sale fall through for other reasons.

Comment: “They” is referring to my municipality after city inspection was completed.  We have an offer on the house as a 2-bathroom, but the city wants us to remove the one in the basement before they will issue the occupancy permit.